# How to make SASS put relative paths in its output

Tags: sass

SASS produces the following code:

```
/* line 22, B:/home/game/www/sass/field/src/globals.sass */
.small-reports .wrap {
  padding: 2px 0 0;
}
```

Does it have a setting to keep the debug info, but make it look like this?:

```
/* line 22, /sass/field/src/globals.sass */
.small-reports .wrap {
  padding: 2px 0 0;
}
```

Different developers have different paths in their environments, while it is handy to have the resulted file in Git.

Comment: It sounds like you are keeping generated code in your version control system which is poor practice. You should look to leverage git hooks to compile your Sass post-commit. Then, you won't have conflicts on debug print outs.

Comment: Could you please provide the SASS code that generates this CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Compass in addition to SASS you have the ability to configure whether the path is relative or absolute with the `relative_assets` property which accepts a boolean value.

See: http://compass-style.org/help/documentation/configuration-reference/