# config.rb for SASS fonts directory path adding slash

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I have set config.rb file as below

```
http_path = "/"
css_dir = ""
sass_dir = "sass"
images_dir = "images"
fonts_dir = 'fonts'
fonts_path = ""
javascripts_dir = "js"
```

Here is my directory path

In the project root

style.css
fonts/my-fonts
sass/style.sass
images/my-all-images

Now when I am trying to add fonts using font-face it is adding leading slash for font directory like `/fonts` but I want it only `fonts`

SASS

```
+font-face("Ubuntu", font-files("ubuntu/ubuntu-r-webfont.eot", "ubuntu/ubuntu-r-webfont.eot?#iefix", "ubuntu/ubuntu-r-webfont.woff", "ubuntu/ubuntu-r-webfont.ttf", "ubuntu/ubuntu-r-webfont.svg#ubunturegular"))
```

Generating CSS

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Ubuntu";
  src: url('/fonts/ubuntu/ubuntu-r-webfont.eot') format('embedded-opentype'), url('/fonts/ubuntu/ubuntu-r-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('/fonts/ubuntu/ubuntu-r-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('/fonts/ubuntu/ubuntu-r-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('/fonts/ubuntu/ubuntu-r-webfont.svg#ubunturegular') format('svg');
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make SASS put relative paths in its output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12508630/how-to-make-sass-put-relative-paths-in-its-output)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set `relative_assets = true` right after path setting in config file.

Here is a sample config example to work on relative assets.

```
# Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "app/css"
sass_dir = "app/css/sass"
images_dir = "app/img"
javascripts_dir = "app/js"
fonts_dir = "app/css/fonts"

output_style = :nested
environment = :development

relative_assets = true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can set http_fonts_path = "fonts" right after path setting in config file.

Here is a sample config example to work.
# Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "css"
sass_dir = "scss"
images_dir = "images"
javascripts_dir = "js"
http_fonts_path = "fonts"
```