# Slick Carousel trying to change file path variable

Tags: sass, carousel, slick.js, compass

I'm using [Slick Carousel](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) with Zurb Foundation and the recommended use it to have the css, js in its own folder in the root directory and when i set my project up like this i can get it to work perfectly.

But I'd like to add it into my current project file structure, like so:

- Project Root

  - Fonts

    - slick.eot
    - slick.svg
    - slick.ttf
    - slick.woff
  - Images

    - Loading.gif
  - JS

    - slick.min.js
  - SCSS

    - slick.scss
  - Stylesheets

    - slick.css

I thought all I'd need to do is change the default variables given in the scss file:

```
$slick-font-path: "./fonts/" !default;
$slick-loader-path: "./" !default;
```

But nothing I try has worked, the compiled css has urls like this:

```
background: #fff url('/images/ajax-loader.gif') center center no-repeat;
```

Comment: What does your config.rb look like?

Comment: I'm using zurb foundations config looks like: '# Require any additional compass plugins here.
add_import_path "bower_components/foundation/scss"

# Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "stylesheets"
sass_dir = "scss"
images_dir = "images"
javascripts_dir = "js"'

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make SASS put relative paths in its output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12508630/how-to-make-sass-put-relative-paths-in-its-output)

Comment: @cimmanon sorry if this is a duplicate but thankyou for your help, i focused on the config.rb that came with slick and that foundation used and was able to fix the carousel, seems so easy now. :)

Answer (score 1):

The two variables `$slick-font-path` and `$slick-loader-path` are only used as a fallback for a missing `image-url` and `font-url` function, which is usually provided by Compass (see: http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/helpers/urls/#image-url).

The only thing you have to do, is to define the default directories for images and fonts in the Gruntfile provided by `grunt-contrib-compass` (https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass)

Here's a snippet from my project's Gruntfile. Just look at the `imagesDir` and `fontsDir` lines in the `dist` section. The rest may look different in your project.

```
compass: {
  options: {
    debugInfo: false,
    imagesDir: ['src/assets/img'],
    raw: [
      'http_path = "/"',
      'Sass::Script::Number.precision = 8',
      'sass_options = {',
      '  :read_cache => true,',
      '}'
    ].join("\n"),
    require: ['sass-globbing'],
    importPath: ['bower_components/foundation/scss', 'bower_components/slick.js/slick'],
    sassDir: ['src/assets/scss']
  },
  dist: {
    options: {
      cssDir: ['dist/assets/css'],
      imagesDir: ['dist/assets/img'],
      fontsDir: ['dist/assets/fonts'],
      environment: 'development',
      force: true,
      javascriptsDir: 'build/js',
      noLineComments: false,
      outputStyle: 'expanded',
      raw: [
        'sass_options = {',
        '  :sourcemap => true', // this set to 'true' has no effect, if you aren't using sass >= 3.3
        '}'
      ].join("\n"),
      sourcemap: true // this set to 'true' has no effect, if you aren't using sass >= 3.3
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.